# Python process increasing memory RAM usage

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ram, python-idle

I have been using python some months and this problem just appear two or three days ago.
At this moment I am running this code in the IDLE 3.4.3 python GUI :

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in x:
   x.append((i * (i + 1))/2)

print(x)
```

But this hasnt output or error(is not the only one), the console just is opened and its waiting(like thinking)
and then i check the process in task admin and i see that the process start in 30-35 mb
and after One or Two minutes the process is consuming:

[image: Problem images]

I have not installed new software or something with the OS, this happen in two different laptops(W7 and W10), could be this code, I know(its works if I create a new empty list) but what about other simple instructions like *1+1* 
I have tried with diferent IDEs, and python versions including architecture.
First I was using iPython notebook and Spyder because I need to plot and Anaconda comes with everything ready, but the kernel always said Busy and without output; I restart, interrupt, new kernel but doesnt work and this happen just this week, because i was working perfectly so I had to remove it because this is happening.

Someone has idea what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what is happening, let me modify your code slightly

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in x:
    x.append((i * (i + 1))/2)
    print(x)
    if len(x) > 20:
        break

print(x)
```

The output looks like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0, 21.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0, 21.0, 231.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0, 21.0, 231.0, 1540.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0, 21.0, 231.0, 1540.0, 7260.0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 1.0, 6.0, 21.0, 55.0, 120.0, 1.0, 21.0, 231.0, 1540.0, 7260.0, 1.0]
```

`append` simply adds a new value to the end of a list, so what you've done is created an infinite loop where `x` is just going to grow bigger and bigger.  Basically every time the iterator draws a number from `x` a new number is added to the end of `x`, so the iterator will always have 5 more numbers to draw before it completes.

As the iterator keeps running, `x` keeps getting bigger and bigger and consuming more and more memory.

To fix this infinite loop you can either store the results in a different list or have a `break` condition like I used above if you really want the results to be appended to `x`.  Also, if you are meaning to replace the values in `x` you can do something like this

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i, v in enumerate(x):
    x[i] = (v * (v + 1))/2

print(x)
```

which outputs

```
[1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: of course its helps, thank you so much for the explanation Joseph, and for the last tip for keep the values in X. really apreciate and you have teach me a new thing for see the output.

Comment: @SirCost: a more pythonic way to write the last code example: `for i, v in enumerate(x): x[i] = v * (v + 1) // 2`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thank you!  The enumerate function totally slipped my mind when I wrote this, but yes, that is much clearer.

Comment: To make the code work the same way on Python 2 and 3, use `//` instead of `/` to get integer results.